Letter-spaced small-caps and German ß
When using letter-spaced small-caps for a German word like “Fußnote”, the “ß” is correctly turned into “ss”, but no space is added between these two symbols, whence they are too close to each other compared to the remaining letters:
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular}[SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=10}]

\begin{document}
\textsc{Fußnote}
\textsc{Fussnote}
\end{document}


As the MWE shows, a workaround is to just write “Fussnote” instead, but I believe there is a more elegant solution to this problem.

what you can do (and normally do do) is to tell latex not to use ligatures when letterspacing. or, ideally, not to use selected ligatures when letterspacing. but you are inserting the ligature directly, so you'd have to have something undo that. probably lua can, but I wonder if it is worth it?

@cfr It's even more intricate. ß is not a ligature, but a character that, in small caps, maps to the single glyph ss (try with  \char\ß). So, unlike with ligatures, there's not even a way to somehow prevent the conversion into two s`.

... in effect, I concur that you'd probably have to stick with the workaround and write Fussnote ...

@Robert that makes sense, thank-you. and, actually, it is obvious it isn't a ligature because, if it was, you'd get ss -> ß, which clearly can't be the case because you don't have to change fonts to type german. (I only just learnt to type ß and didn't think I'd need it so soon.)
